# Conjunction to use after "one of the following" + comma-separated list

Tags: grammaticality, conjunctions, lists

In the following sentence, which conjunction (`and` or `or`) should be used?

> One from these programming languages is good: PHP, Java, `and/or` Perl.

If I use `and` since the sentence is referring to a collection of programming languages, does it not disagree with the subject `One`?

If I use `or` since the subject is `One`, will it be semantically wrong since the sentence is referring to a collection of programming languages?

Can the sentence be rewritten in one line so that the decision to choose which conjunction to use can be avoided?

Answer (score 2):

The colon is a good choice. There is a complete sentence before the list, so a sentence end punctuation works well.

Rather than worry about or/and, just present the list with no conjunction. The list isn't part of a sentence, so there is no need to have a conjunction.

> One of these is a good language: Perl, Python, Ruby.

Alternatively, rephrase to include the list in the sentence:

> Only one of Perl, Python and Ruby is a good programming language.  ("or" would also work instead of and)